# Sub plotting a function with one input and 3 outputs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to plot three different graphs. h vs T, h vs P, and h vs rho. When i run the program i am getting three different graphs but no data on it. 
I'm not sure what im doing wrong.

Here is my code for the plot

```
for h=0:1:1000
[ T,P,rho ] = stdatm( h );
hold all 
subplot(1,3,1)
plot(T,h,'r')

subplot(1,3,2)
plot(P,h)

subplot(1,3,3)
plot(rho,h)
end
```

here is my function code

```
function [ T,P,rho ] = stdatm( h )
T0=288.16;
P0=101.325;
rho0=1.225;
a=-6.5*10^-3;
b=3*10^-3;
c=-4.5*10^-3;
d=4.0*10^-3;
R=286.9;
g=9.81;

T1=T0+a*11000;
P1=P0*(T1/T0)^(-g/(a*R));
rho1=rho0*(T1/T0)^((-g/(a*R))-1);

T2=T1;
P2=P1*exp((-g/(R*T2))*(25000-11000));
rho2=rho1*exp((-g/(R*T2))*(25000-11000));

T3=T2+b*(47000-25000);
P3=P2*(T3/T2)^(-g/(b*R));
rho3=rho2*(T3/T2)^((-g/(b*R))-1);

T4=T3;
P4=P3*exp((-g/(R*T4))*(53000-47000));
rho4=rho3*exp((-g/(R*T4))*(53000-47000));

T5=T4+c*(79000-53000);
P5=P4*(T5/T4)^(-g/(c*R));
rho5=rho4*(T5/T4)^((-g/(c*R))-1);

T6=T5;
P6=P5*exp((-g/(R*T6))*(90000-79000));
rho6=rho5*exp((-g/(R*T6))*(90000-79000));

T7=T6+d*(100000-90000);
P7=P6*(T7/T6)^(-g/(d*R));
rho7=rho6*(T7/T6)^((-g/(d*R))-1);

if h<=11000 
T=T0+a*h;
P=P0*(T/T0)^(-g/(a*R));
rho=rho0*(T/T0)^((-g/(a*R))-1);
elseif h>11000 && h<=25000
T=T1;
P=P1*exp((-g/(R*T))*(h-11000));
rho=rho1*exp((-g/(R*T))*(h-11000));
elseif h>25000 && h<=47000 
T=T2+b*(h-25000);
P=P2*(T/T2)^(-g/(b*R));
rho=rho2*(T/T2)^((-g/(b*R))-1);
elseif h>47000 && h<=53000
T=T3;
P=P3*exp((-g/(R*T3))*(h-47000));
rho=rho3*exp((-g/(R*T3))*(h-47000));
elseif h>53000 && h<=79000
T=T4+c*(h-53000);
P=P4*(T/T4)^(-g/(c*R));
rho=rho4*(T/T4)^((-g/(c*R))-1);
elseif h>79000 && h<=90000
T=T5;
P=P5*exp((-g/(R*T))*(h-79000));
rho=rho5*exp((-g/(R*T))*(h-79000));
elseif h>90000 && h<=100000
T=T6+d*(h-90000);
P=P6*(T/T6)^(-g/(d*R));
rho=rho6*(T/T6)^((-g/(d*R))-1);

end
```

Comment: Plotting each point one-by-one is super inefficient. Why not build up T, P and rho vectors (each with 1000 elements) and then do the 3 plots...

Comment: Agree with @Justin.  Generate all of the points first in the vectors, then just call `plot/subplot` once per plot.  Doing it in a loop is inefficient, not to mention that it will bring a toll onto the graphics system.

Comment: When I run my code im not getting my vecors h,T,P, and rho to have a dimension of 100.                                                                                    for h=0:1:100
    [ T,P,rho ] = stdatm( h );
end
    hold on
    subplot(1,3,1)
    plot(T,h)
    
    subplot(1,3,2)
    plot(P,h)
    
    subplot(1,3,3)
    plot(rho,h)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `hold` per each of the subplots:

```
for h=0:1:1000
[ T,P,rho ] = stdatm( h );
subplot(1,3,1)
plot(T,h,'r')
hold on 
subplot(1,3,2)
plot(P,h)
hold on 
subplot(1,3,3)
plot(rho,h)
hold on 
end
hold off
```

[image]

Vectorizing the function `stdatm` would be a better solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

When i run my code I'm only getting vectors of one dimension for h,T,P,rho. Thus one data pt on each plot.

```
for h=0:1:100
[ T,P,rho ] = stdatm( h );
end
hold on
subplot(1,3,1)
plot(T,h)

subplot(1,3,2)
plot(P,h)

subplot(1,3,3)
plot(rho,h)
```

Comment: You overwrite the values of T, P, rho in every loop. You might want to do `[T(h+1), P(h+1), rho(h+1)] = stdatm(h);` Additionally, use preallocation àla `T = zeros(1,101); ...` before the loop for efficiency.